# Error adding "Azure Mobile Apps Table Controller"

Tags: azure-mobile-services, visual-studio-2017, azure-sdk-.net

I have a fresh install of Visual Studio 2017, RTM (15.0.0+26228.9).
I created a new project from the "Azure Mobile App" template. (created fine)
Then, under the Controllers folder, I right-clicked "Add Controller...".
I tried each of the following 2 templates, and received an error on each:

```
Azure Mobile Apps Custom Controller
Azure Mobile Apps Table Controller
```

Considering the **Table Controller** first, I received the error: *There was an error running the selected code generator: 'A TwoWay or OneWayToSource binding cannot work on the read-only property 'EntityTypes' of type 'Microsoft.Cct.MobileApps.WebExtensions.Scaffolding.MobileAppsTableControllerViewModel'.'*

The **Custom Controller** allowed me to select the controller name, then showed the error: *There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Could not find template '' in these folders ['C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Microsoft Azure\Mobile Apps\2.0\Scaffold'], including sub-folders.'*

The standard Web API Controller - Empty worked fine.

Azure App Services Tools shows v3.0.0 (15.0.30209.0).

**EDIT 4/1/2017**: Reproduced the table controller symptom with a fresh Mobile App project, same error for table creation, even after reinstalling with latest tool version, as directed in comments:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

-John

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue with the TableController? I had the exact same scenario as you have described. The selected answer fixed my problem with custom controller but I still cannot create a table controller!

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54917, download `AzureMobileAppsSdkPackagesV2.0.msi` only and install it. Then try to add a new custom controller once more and the problem should be gone.

Comment: I downloaded the AzureMobileAppsSDKPackagesV2.0.mis, and installed it. It completed fine. I can successfully make a Custom controller now, but still not a Table controller - same error. I reran the install, it asks to uninstall or repair. I asked to repair, same outcome with controllers. The Add Remove Programs reports 2.0.50228.0.

Comment: For the Table Controller I guess the problem may be related to your class structure. Can you add the code to your question?

Comment: Which class structure? EntityData?

Comment: Not sure it's related to my class structure, I created a new Mobile App project, then immediately tried to crate a Table Controller and experienced the same symptom. I edited my original post with the OOB project structure.

Comment: @mister_giga, not sure what you're asking?

Comment: Did you ever get to solve this issue? I am having the exact same problem. I also found this https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/31200/working-with-xamarin-forms-mobile-app-backend-cann.html